# How to put a conditional construct in \edef

Tags: conditionals, expansion

`\ifthenelse` works fine normally, but when used in `\edef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\testing[1][]{%
    \edef\tmp{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{Blank}{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
    \testing
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal 
                  {}{}
l.10
```

I also get this error when I use `\ifthenelse` in a `\putbib` command (from the `bibunits` package).

Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 6):

Put `\noexpand` in front of the inner macros which should not be expanded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\testing[1][]{%
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{#1}{}}{Blank}{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
    \testing
\end{document}
```

If you actually want the full expression be expanded, then you can only use code which is fully expandable and do not use temporary assignments etc.
You could also move the `\edef` into the *true* an *false* clauses instead.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to use `\ifthenelse` in an `\edef`; Martin's approach will only defer the evaluation and so the `\edef` does only expansion of `#1` (which might be what you want).

In order to test if an argument is empty, the safer test is

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  <empty>
\else
  <not empty>
\fi
```

One can also define a "TF" variant:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifEmptyTF}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

and then your code can become

```
\newcommand{\testing}[1][]{\ifEmptyTF{#1}{Blank}{#1}}
```

An "expanded" version can be obtained with the help of `\pdfstrcmp` (called `\strcmp` in XeTeX):

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifExpandedEmptyTF}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

(**pdftexcmds** defines `\pdf@strcmp` to do the right thing independent of the typesetting engine used).

For example `\ifEmpty{\empty}` will evaluate to false, while `\ifExpandedEmptyTF{\empty}` will evaluate to true, given that `\empty` is defined by

```
\def\empty{}
```